# Error Installing React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Whenever I do a `npm init` then `npm install react` - I get this error

> ── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.3.0
>
> npm WARN baobab-react@0.1.1 requires a peer of react@>=0.13.0 <1.0.0  but none was installed.
>   npm WARN fixed-data-table@0.4.7 requires a
>   peer of react@>=0.13.0 <0.15.0 || ^0.14.0-beta3 but none was
>   installed.
>   npm WARN react-native@0.30.0 requires a peer of
>   react@~15.2.0 but none was installed.
>   npm WARN react-router@0.13.5
>   requires a peer of react@0.13.x||0.14.x but none was installed. npm
>   ERR! code 1

This is my node v6.3.0 annd npm 3.10.3 versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install react --no-optional
```

Comment: I'm getting this error  UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.3.0
  fbjs@0.8.3 
  │ └── object-assign@4.1.0 
  └── object-assign@4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Inside your project directory, can you please first run the following commands:-

```
1) rm -rf node_modules
2) Try installig react again now and other packages which are in your package.json file.
```