# npm install: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@0.14.8

Tags: npm, npm-install

This seems like a duplicate to [Error Installing React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38696242/error-installing-react), but since that question didn't get a (working answer) I figured I'd re-ask it.

I've got a `package.json` with a bunch of dependencies, and they all install fine ... except one.  For reasons I have yet to fathom, every time I `npm install anything` (it doesn't actually happen on a plain `npm install`, although it might if I cleared things first) I see:

```
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@0.14.8
```

There are no other packages mentioned with it, and it doesn't matter what package I install; even if it has nothing to do with React I still get it.

Per the question I linked I tried:

```
npm install --save --no-optional react
```

But it (just like `npm install anything`) just results in that `UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY` message.

If anyone could explain how I could even start to find the cause of this error, I'd certainly appreciate it.